# How to bind a ListBox to a DataTable from a session object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, datatable

I have a session object that contains a DataTable from my previous page,
and i would like to bind this DataTable to a ListBox.

I've done this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Session["bestStocks"] !=null)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           

            dt = (DataTable)Session["bestStocks"];

            DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
            BestStockslb.DataSource = dt;
            BestStockslb.DataBind();
        }
     }
 }
```

I get this result:

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate [Why does my listbox populated by datatable show "System.Data.DataRow" instead of the actual values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21949578/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have forgot the DataTextField and DataValueField

```
 dt = (DataTable)Session["bestStocks"];

DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
BestStockslb.DataSource = dt;
BestStockslb.DataTextField =  "Name";
BestStockslb.DataValueField =  "ID"; 
BestStockslb.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
BestStockslb.DataSource = dt;
```

To:

```
BestStockslb.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

And you also need to set the DataTextField and DataValueField Properties of `BestStockslb` to link to the required fields in the returned data.  This is why you are getting the DataRowView output.

You could also remove `DataView dv = new DataView(dt);` as it looks like you are not using it.