# C# Winforms Bind ListBox to DataTable Issue

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, listbox

Well, I've ran into a problem when binding ListBox control to DataTable.

Code:

```
using (DbWrapper db = DbFactory.GetConnection("SQLite").WrapIn<MyDbWrapper>())
{
    db.Open();

    DataTable results = db.ExecuteQuery("SELECT id,title FROM schedule");

    ScheduleList.DataSource = results;
    ScheduleList.DisplayMember = "title";
    ScheduleList.ValueMember = "id";
}
```

This code is supposed to receive data from my SQLite database, and bind it to my ScheduleList, but when I compile I see my ListBox filled with System.Data.DataRowView strings.

[image]

There's no problems with database. The application is receiving data, and the data is correct. If I iterate through my datatable I will get id and title as column names, so theres nothing wrong with them.

I've read that the problem may be solved by changing binding order or setting ListBox.Sorted property to false. I've tried it all and still no success.

Any suggestions?
Are there any other solutions except iterating over datarows and adding them manually?

Best Regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803859/how-to-bind-a-listbox-to-a-datatable-from-a-session-object

Comment: Well, it is, but solutions posted there didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. The ListBox wasn't reacting to DisplayMember and ValueMember changes because of inappropriate code in custom ListBox DrawItem event.

Comment: I suspected something like that because my testing, and indeed every search result I found, suggested the code you had ought be working well.

Answer (score 4):

I used this code and it worked.

```
DataTable oTable = new DataTable();
oTable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
oTable.Columns.Add("TITLE", typeof(string));

DataRow oNewRow = null;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    oNewRow = oTable.NewRow();

    oNewRow["ID"] = i;
    oNewRow["TITLE"] = "Title_" + i.ToString();

    oTable.Rows.Add(oNewRow);
}

listBox1.DataSource = oTable;
listBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
listBox1.DisplayMember = "TITLE";
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
you may need to give tha datasource first and then declare the value-display members.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but I've already fixed the problem. It was caused by custom DrawItem event.

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange the statements:

```
ScheduleList.DisplayMember = "title";
ScheduleList.ValueMember = "id";
ScheduleList.DataSource = results;
```