# Why does my listbox populated by datatable show "System.Data.DataRow" instead of the actual values?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I am trying to populate a listview or a listbox from database using C#. I am using datatable to grab data. I am using this code below. But listview or the listbox is populating something like `"System.Data.DataRow"` text. Where I have something else in my database.

```
query = "select itemtag from tbl_inventory order by itemtag";
DataTable dt = con.DataTable(query);
int count = dt.Rows.Count;
if (count >0)
{
    //listView1.Items.Clear();
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        //listView1.Items.Add(dt);
        listBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

[image: As you see I am getting output like "System.Data.DataRow"], where I
have something else in my database

Answer (score 3):

If your using a listbox then directly use the DATASOURCE property...

```
ListBox1.DataSource
```

1. [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615069/how-to-refresh-datasource-of-a-listbox-in-c-sharp-winforms)
2. [Link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. [Link3](http://www.dotnetperls.com/listbox)

Answer (score 2):

Unless your DataTable is 1-dimensional (in which case, why are you using a DataTable), then your code should be:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i][columnIndexHere].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 listBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());
```

But, this will inserts only first column data into listview. if you want to add subitem also then use it.

```
 ListItem li = listBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());
 li.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
 li.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[i][2].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
listBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i][0]+"|"+dt.Rows[i][1] +"vs" + dt.Rows[i][3]);
```